# Where to put/find schema.xml and other config files in solarium using Yii2?

Tags: php, solr, yii2, solarium

I'm trying to use Solr through solarium under Yii 2 Framework, after Googling for many hours i still don't know where is the config files.

I only have solarium folder under vendor,

```
--- vendor
  --- solarium 
    --- solarium 
    --- examples 
    --- library 
    --- phar
    --- tests 
    ...
```

but i don't know how to add the config files, and what if i need to create multiple indexes/cores.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [yii2-solr](https://github.com/Sammaye/yii2-solr) package. From their website, you need to add these configurations to your `@app/config/main.php` file.

```
'components' => [
    ...
    'solr' => [
        'class' => 'sammaye\solr\Client',
        'options' => [
            'endpoint' => [
                'solr1' => [
                    'host' => '10.208.225.66',
                    'port' => '8983',
                    'path' => '/solr'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
    ...
]
```

Comment: I am using it already, but i don't know how to add the config files, and what if i need to create multiple indexes/cores, i can't find these information in there document.

Comment: You should add such information to your question (about using specific extension).

Comment: @Dev.Tareq read my answer properly, The configuration goes into any of Yii's config files which is autoloaded. Either `@app/config.main.php` or `@common/config/main.php`